# From features to sequence

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow, time-series, feature-engineering

I want to train a supervised algorithm capable to rebuild from features (like mean, std, feature from frequency domain etc.) the original signal, this signals is discrete and have different lengths. Since there are a lot of Algorithms and I dont have the proper background to choose the most appropriate one, I want to ask if anyone can suggest me the one that fit the best for my problem.

Comment: If such features are present, what is the benefit of using supervised learning? Can't it be done with just inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to extract a feature in common of different signals, to do that I have extracted different features in different domains such time and frequency, I have built an auto encoder to do a non-linear PCA using as data the different features. About my question: After the decoder have reconstructed the features using latent space, using the features I want to reconstruct the signal to see what looks like, so,I cannot use Inverse FFT because I "lost" it by transform it in features and elaborating it in the auto encoder.

Comment: Sorry I do not follow your rationale, specifically *why* an autoencoder is needed. Given you have already extracted features in time/frequency domain, there are plenty of tools to reconstruct the signal in signal processing area. I fail to see what benefits it brings to complicate thing with another (unrelated) set of tools.

Comment: I'm using an Auto encoder since I want to perform a dimensionality reduction (PCA) in a non-linear way. So, starting with many features, I want to see if I can describe my signals with only few features (I'm starting with 33 features and I want to reduce like to 1 or 2). In summary, I want to do that, but as I said in the post, I don't have a proper curriculum, so I don't really know if there are better paths to follow, I'm open to new solutions.
I took the idea from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-autoencoders-outperform-pca-in-dimensionality-reduction-1ae44c68b42f

Comment: And here too: https://towardsdatascience.com/autoencoders-vs-pca-when-to-use-which-73de063f5d7